# Why massive elementary particles come in different flavors?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, standard-model, elementary-particles

Neutrinos come in 3 flavors: electron neutrino, muon neutrino, and tau neutrino.

Quarks come in 6 flavors: up, down, top, bottom, strange and charm.

And lets not forget electron, muons and taus too.

Photon is not a massive particle since it has 0 invariant mass.

Why only massive particles can come in many flavors? It is just a co-incidence so maybe there could be more flavors we haven't discovered?

Comment: If there is a fourth generation of particles that couple to the weak neutral current, its lightest member is too massive to contribute to the known decay width of the $Z$ boson. [One source](https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/ask-ethan-why-are-there-only-three-generations-of-particles-700af1fb45bd), complete with the famous $N_\nu = 3$ plot from ALEPH at CERN.

Comment: Please see this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407688/why-are-there-only-four-fundamental-interactions-of-nature/407696#407696, my general answer to "why"questions.  ( incidentally you have forgotten the gluons)

Answer (score 0):

No one knows why the universe is so constructed; as far as is known, the two more massive generations aren't *required* to account for phenomena or solve problems in the realm of the first generation.

As pointed out by Rob in his comment, experimental data can be used to place a limit of 3 on the possible number of generations.